# Visualising data in 3 different google line charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Hello guys so i have script.js which is fetching data from my database (with read.php as API) and storing data in the table in my index.html file. The columns from database are: Date, Temperature, Pressure and RPM. What i have now is 3 charts that includes 3 lines --> temperature + pressure + rpm. But how can i split the data to show each element in own google line chart. So i would like to have 3 line charts: 1 chart for temperature + 1 chart for pressure + 1 chart for rpm. And I must keep 1 table with all data.

```js
"use strict";

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['controls', 'line', 'table']});

document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', getData);

async function getData() {

  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/read1.php");
  let json = await response.json();    

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'temperature');
  data.addColumn('number', 'pressure');
  data.addColumn('number', 'rpm');

  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      addRow(json[i]);
      data.addRow(Object.values(json[i]));
    }

  var chartTemp = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Line',
    containerId: 'temperature_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chart: {
        title: 'Temperature',
        subtitle: ''
      },
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [1 , 2]
    }
  });
  chartTemp.draw();

  var chartPres = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Line',
    containerId: 'pressure_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chart: {
        title: 'Pressure',
        subtitle: ''
      },
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [1 , 3]
    }
  });
  chartPres.draw();

  var chartRPM = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Line',
    containerId: 'rpm_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chart: {
        title: 'RPM',
        subtitle: ''
      },
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [1 , 4]
    }
  });
  chartRPM.draw();

  var chartTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {}
  });
  chartTable.draw();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Sensor Data</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
       <header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
          <h1><center>Sensor data</center></h1>
        </div>
       </header> 

        <section id="mainpic6">
        </section>

        <h1><center>Visualisation of sensor data --> last 100 records</center></h1>

        <div class="container">


        <section id="main4">

                <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Temperature</th>
                  <th>Pressure</th>
                  <th>RPM</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="table_data">
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>

                    <button id="get">GET</button>

              </tbody>
            </table>

        </section>

            <div></div>

            <aside id="sidebar2">

                <div>Temperature Chart</div>
                <div id="temperature_data"></div>
                <div>Pressure Chart</div>
                <div id="pressure_data"></div>
                <div>RPM Chart</div>
                <div id="rpm_data"></div>

            </aside>



        </div>





        <footer id="main-footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 Arturas Website</p>
        </footer>

        <script src="script/script2.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Thats my script and at the moment i have 3 charts but they all show 3 elements in it, how can i split it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommend using the [`ChartWrapper` Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject) to draw the charts.

google charts also has a Table chart, so you can use it, instead of manually building the table.
the Table chart produces a normal html table, so you can apply any styles you currently have.
plus it has sorting built in...

first, add the `'controls'` and `'table'` packages to the load statement.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'line', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', getData);
});
```

also recommend using the promise the load statement returns,
to ensure google charts has loaded, before assigning the click event, see above...

next, the ChartWrappers have a `view` property.
this allows you to apply a view directly on the chart.
which you can use to control which columns from the data table are included in the chart...

```
var chartTemp = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Line',
  containerId: 'temperature_data',
  dataTable: data,
  options: {
    chart: {
      title: 'Temperature',
      subtitle: ''
    },
    height: 300
  },
  view: {
    columns: [0, 1]  // <-- include x-axis and temperature columns
  }
});
chartTemp.draw();
```

---

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'line', 'table']
}).then(getData);

function getData() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'temperature');
  data.addColumn('number', 'pressure');
  data.addColumn('number', 'rpm');

  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    data.addRow([(i + 1) + '/2020', (5 * i), (10 * i), (15 * i)]);
  }

  var chartTemp = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Line',
    containerId: 'temperature_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chart: {
        title: 'Temperature',
        subtitle: ''
      },
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 1]
    }
  });
  chartTemp.draw();

  var chartPres = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Line',
    containerId: 'pressure_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chart: {
        title: 'Pressure',
        subtitle: ''
      },
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 2]
    }
  });
  chartPres.draw();

  var chartRPM = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Line',
    containerId: 'rpm_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chart: {
        title: 'RPM',
        subtitle: ''
      },
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 3]
    }
  });
  chartRPM.draw();

  var chartTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_data',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {}
  });
  chartTable.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="temperature_data"></div>
  <div id="pressure_data"></div>
  <div id="rpm_data"></div>
  <div id="table_data"></div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

the table chart should use a `<div>` element, similar to the other charts.

try replacing the following...

```
           <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Temperature</th>
              <th>Pressure</th>
              <th>RPM</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="table_data">
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>

                <button id="get">GET</button>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

with...

```
<div id="table_data"></div>
<button id="get">GET</button>
```

as for styles, not sure how they are being applied.

if you are using the id on the `<tbody id="table_data">` element...

```
#table_data {
  /* styles */
}
```

then replace with...

```
#table_data tbody {
  /* styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick responf i try to implement it into my code but it seems not working with the data from my database

Comment: my table has no data and none of the charts are working

Comment: script2.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: addRow is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.getData (script2.js:19)

Comment: will you please update the question with the latest version of your code?

Comment: remove this line --> `addRow(json[i]);` -- the function was removed...

Comment: ive removed that line and now it seems working just 2 problems now: 1. table doesnt take my style  2. RPM shows everywhere 1,5 instead of in the range of 1480-1530

Comment: see __EDIT__ above. -- not sure what you mean by _RPM shows everywhere 1,5 instead of in the range of 1480-1530_

Comment: i dont know how to change the width of the table en th

Comment: its just data rims per minute and the value has to be between 1480 and 1530 but in table i get just 1,5 everywhere